# In math mode, how can I type a symbol that is the vertical reflection of \check{-}?

Tags: symbols

This is what `\check{-}` looks like: $\check{-}$

I'd like to type something that is a vertical reflection of that: a "hat" accent below a horizontal bar. How can I put a hat accent below the `-`?

Comment: Is this posting essentially a duplicate of your parallel posting, [In math mode, I have access to \veebar, but not \barvee? Why?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/201027/5001)

Comment: @Mico No it is not, because the symbols look *very* different. I am playing with the possibility of using one or the other, but the hat/check versions have a much smaller v, and a longer bar compared to veebar/barvee.

Answer (score 1):

A poor man's solution using `\scalebox`:

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\reflcheck}{%
  \mathbin{%
    \mathpalette\@reflcheck{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@reflcheck}{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{\raisebox{-0.65ex}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{$\m@th\check{-}$}}}}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\check{-}\reflcheck$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why is it called "poor man's" solution?

Comment: @user89 It is a desperate hack under desperate situations. Also you have to adjust the sizes for super/subscript etc. That is why. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\begin{document}
$\check{-}$ $\barwedge$
\end{document}
```

[image]

There's also an `amssymb` version where the wedge is taller.

Comment: Hi Erik. That's not quite what I am looking for. I wouldn't say the two symbols you have there are mirrors of each other :p

Comment: @user89 Well, you did say reflection :) I guess Heiko's answer to your other question is what you were looking for.