# In math mode, I have access to \veebar, but not \barvee? Why?

Tags: symbols

As the title notes, I have access to `\veebar`, but `\barvee` produces an undefined control sequence error. These are the math related packages I am loading:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
```

Comment: answering just the reason why: because nobody had asked for it when the `amsfonts` were constructed.  math symbology is an expanding universe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## LuaTeX, XeTeX

Package `unicode-math` (requires LuaTeX or XeTeX) provides a `\barvee` (U+22BD NOR):

```
\tracinglostchars=2 % report, if a font misses a glyph
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\begin{document}
  % Latin Modern
  \[ \veebar \barvee \]
  %
  \setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}
  \[ \veebar \barvee \]
  %
  \setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
  \[ \veebar \barvee \]
  %
  \setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
  \[ \veebar \barvee \]
  \setmathfont{texgyretermes-math.otf}
  \[ \veebar \barvee \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## Constructed solution

The following example constructs a `\barvee` from `\vee` and `\minus` with using the dimensions of `\veebar`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\barvee}{%
  \mathbin{%
    \mathpalette\@barvee{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@barvee}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: unused
  \sbox0{$#1\veebar\m@th$}%
  \sbox2{%
    \hbox to \wd0{%
      \hss
      \resizebox{1.05\wd0}{\height}{$#1-\m@th$}%
      \hss
    }%
  }%
  \sbox4{%
    \resizebox{\wd0}{.7\ht0}{$#1\vee\m@th$}%
  }%
  \sbox6{$#1\vcenter{}$}
  \ht2=\ht6 %
  \vbox to \ht0{%
    \copy2 %
    \vss
    \copy4 %
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \[ \veebar\barvee^{\veebar\barvee^{\veebar\barvee}} \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## Very poor man's solution using accent

There is an `\bar` accent that can be put over `\vee`. However the line is thinner and smaller than the line in `\veebar`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
  \[ \veebar \bar\vee \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## Poor man solution using `\overline`

1010011010 suggested to use `\overline`. An additional `\mathbin` is needed, because `\overline` strips this property from its contents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\providecommand*{\poorbarvee}{%
  \mathbin{%
    \overline{\vee}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
  \[ a \veebar b \]
  \[ a \poorbarvee b \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

It also classifies as "poor man's solution", because

- the line is now too long, because it also covers the side bearings.
- As in the previous solution, the `\vee` part is too large, the gap too small
- and the line does not have round line caps.

Comment: Surprised you didn't mention an `\overline` with adjusted dimensions. Or am I wrong to assume this is possible?

Comment: @1010011010 `\overline` can also be used as poor man's solution, because this solution has its limitations.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I like your constructed solution. I know it's a shot in the dark to ask, but is there a recommended resource that you know of that teaches the craft of constructing LaTeX symbols?

Comment: @AlbertoTakase The basis is of course "The TeXbook" by Donald E. Knuth. Then, learning by doing, writing answers, ... If your are interested in constructing symbols, then the answers in [tag:symbols] could be a starting point. I remember having written quite a few answers to construct symbols, some with comments that explain at least a bit.